# Call multiple functions inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to import a text file and return the text into a list of strings for each word while also returning lower case and no punctuation.

I've created the following code but this doesn't split each word into a string. Also is it possible to add `.lower()` into the comprehension?

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """Turns file into a list of strings, lower case, and no punctuation"""
    return [word for line in open(words_file, 'r') for word in line.split(string.punctuation)]
```

Comment: Please add example input, what you want to get as output, and the actual output you are getting.

Comment: Why does the process need to be a list comprehension?

Comment: This doesn't need to be a comprehension. Just figured it would be the smallest amount of code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add `.lower` to the comprehension. It should probably happen in `word`. Also the following code probably does not split each word because of `string.punctuation`. If you are just trying to split on whitespace calling `.split()` without arguments will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list comprehension that should do everything you want:

```
[word.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() for line in open(words_file) for word in line.split()]
```

You need to split on whitespace (the default) to separate the words. Then you can transform each resulting string to remove the punctuation and make it lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [mapping to translate the words](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and use it in a generator function.

```
import string
def words(filepath):
    '''Yield words from filepath with punctuation and whitespace removed.'''

    # map uppercase to lowercase and punctuation/whitespace to an empty string
    t = str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase,
                      string.ascii_lowercase,
                      string.punctuation + string.whitespace)

    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.strip().split():
                word = word.translate(t)
                # don't yield empty strings
                if word:
                    yield word
```

Usage

```
for word in words('foo.txt'):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
def read_words(words_file):
    """Turns file into a list of strings, lower case, and no punctuation"""
    with open(words_file, 'r') as f:
        lowered_text = f.read().lower()
    return ["".join(char for char in word if char not in string.punctuation) for word in lowered_text.split()]
```